# Using nl2br Displays html tags in my textarea

Tags: php, html, nl2br

I just started using [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) in my php site. 
Basically I am using it to give a nice layout to a 'bio' field in case the user presses enter.

Problem is that it stores the exact line break tag `<br>` in my database and it does the same when i display the same data from my server to a text area.

How can i prevent the textarea from displaying the actual `<br>` tag
here's my sample code

```
//grabbing the data in the text area field
$bio = nl2br(htmlentities(trim($_POST['bio'])));

//displaying the value from the database
$row = mysql_fetch_array($my_select_query);
<textarea><?php echo $row['bio']?; ></textarea>
```

I get something that looks like this in my textarea
[image: Tesxt area result]

how can i avoid this?

Comment: Could you post more PHP code? That `$bio` variable is never used... `$my_select_query` is never initialized...

Comment: `nl2br()` is used to display text that was entered in a textarea (with linebreaks), in a non-text area. Do not use it before storing in your database. Only use it when displaying.

Comment: _“Problem is that it stores the exact line break tag <br> in my database”_ – not “it” does that – _you_ do. So just don’t! Use that function when you _output_ that data, not when you put it into the database. And don’t use it when you are displaying the content as value of a textarea. Really simple, isn’t it?

Comment: Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/users/248129/richard-jp-le-guen, i think i got everything working now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't `nl2br()`, or even `htmlentities()` input before storing it in your database. I tend to keep it reasonably raw, which gives more scope to change things later on.

If this is already in production, you could create your own `br2nl()` function which reverses the effects of `nl2br()`:

```
function br2nl($input) {
    return preg_replace('/<br\\s*?\/??>/i', '', $input);
}
```

Comment: Wait, so it really isn't necessary to store the <br/> tags in my database right?

Comment: Not only isn't it necessary, it makes your life more difficult later on!

Answer (score 0):

Use the nl2br function when showing the field on a page, not when editing.  This way the field is stored with embedded line breaks instead of as a HTML fragment, which means it could be used also for other purposes.

Comment: The nl2br function does not when dispalyoing the data from the databae. Everything still appears on one line.

Comment: Are you saying that the nl2br function does not actually translate line breaks to break tags?

Comment: Oh I think i figured how it works now.
When I am displaying data in a textarea, it actually works.
But when i am displaying the data as ordinary html (not in a textarea or input), i am using a function that reverses ln2br

Answer (score 0):

Do not use nl2br to record information in the bank.

So when it is displayed it will respect the line breaks previously inserted in the text area.

```
//grabbing the data in the text area field
$bio = trim($_POST['bio']);

//displaying the value from the database
$row = mysql_fetch_array($my_select_query);
<textarea><?php echo $row['bio']?; ></textarea>
```